# Angular momentum of light

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, angular-momentum, classical-electrodynamics, polarization, helicity

Can someone explain the classical angular momentum in electromagnetic theory of light?
If I shine elliptically polarised em wave on a black disc it rotates.
I would like to know how to calculate torque in classical picture.

Comment: What have you found out so far?

Comment: If you consider an electron, then the electric field drives it along an ellipse.

Comment: The classic answer to this is [Beth's 1936 measurement](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.50.115) of the effect, which analyzes the problem in both the classical and quantum-mechanical frameworks. Beth used a clever arrangement of quarter- and half-wave plates to extract angular momentum 4&hbar; from each polarized photon.

Comment: @rob A non paywalled version of Beth is [Richard A. Beth, "Mechanical Detection and Measurement of the Angular Momentum of Light" *Phys. Rev.* **50** July 15 1936](http://users.df.uba.ar/schmiegelow/materias/FT2_2010_1C/extra/PhysRev.50.115.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

## The Result You Seek

The Wikipedia page on [angular momentum of light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_of_light) gives the classical angular momentum as:

$$\frac{\epsilon_0}{2i\omega}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \left(\mathbf{E}^\ast\times\mathbf{E}\right)d^{3}\mathbf{r}  +\frac{\epsilon_0}{2i\omega}\sum_{i=x,y,z}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \left({E^i}^{\ast}\left(\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{\nabla}\right)E^{i}\right)d^{3}\mathbf{r}\tag{1}$$

when the positive frequency part alone of the fields is kept (hence the complex conjugates).

Angular momentum is a great deal easier to think about when the field vectors are written as the Riemann-Silberstein vectors, which I discuss in [my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80039/26076). These are the rank-2, skew-symmetric Faraday tensor in disguise. The first term in (1) is the spin angular momentum, and, rewritten in positive frequency Riemann-Silberstein vectors when everything is roughly paraxial (i.e. near to a plane wave) it reads:

$$\hat{\mathbf{z}}\frac{1}{\omega}\int \left(|\mathbf{F}_+|^2-|\mathbf{F}_-|^2\right)d^{3}\mathbf{r}$$

i.e. $\frac{1}{\omega}$ times the right polarized energy density less the left polarized energy density in the direction of propagation of the light. Orbital angular momentum vanishes in the paraxial limit and so the last equation is the total angular momentum in this case.

## What This Means and Sketch of How It Is Derived

It is important to recall how this equation is derived: one imagines an electromagnetic field crossing the boundary into a conductive medium and being absorbed there. In general, the currents induced by the incident field feel a torque. One then calculates the moment of the Lorentz force on the currents in the medium to calculate the angular impulse exerted on the medium, exactly analogously with method 3 of the linear momentum / impulse calculation in [my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/72688/26076). The angular momentum density $\left(|\mathbf{F}_+|^2-|\mathbf{F}_-|^2\right)/\omega$ calculated from this most basic (in the sense of fundamental) Newtonian-Maxwell physics is the difference between the intensities of the circularly polarized base states. This calculation says that the right and left circularly polarized components transfer angular momentum $\pm E/\omega$ in the direction of light propagation, respectively, whenever energy $E$ is absorbed. So now we see that, if the photon has energy $h\nu$, then if a high number of them are to transfer the same angular momentum as classical physics reckons, the photon's angular momentum has to be $\pm h\nu/\omega$ or $\pm \hbar$ in the direction of its propagation for right and left circularly polarized photons, respectively.

## Lastly

A classic paper here, which actually measures the torque exerted on a quarter wave plate (which takes linear polarised, *i.e.* zero angular momentum, light in and outputs circularly polarised light). The paper, as mentioned in the comments, is:

[R. Beth, "Mechanical Detection and Measurement of the Angular Momentum of Light", Phys. Rev. **50** 1936 pp115-127](http://users.df.uba.ar/schmiegelow/materias/FT2_2010_1C/extra/PhysRev.50.115.pdf)

The torque exerted on a quarter wave plate when polarised light (any polarisation, as long as we have a pure polarisation state) is shone through it is $\frac{P}{\omega}$, where $P$ is the power of the light beam.

Comment: Technically Beth measured the angular momentum transferred to a half-wave plate, but that's just two quarter-wave plates stuck together.

Comment: Note however that a circularly polarised plane wave does *not* carry angular momentum along its propagation direction if the Poynting vector is used. As $\bf P = \epsilon_0 \bf E \times \bf B$ is parallel to the propagation direction, $\bf J = \bf r \times \bf J$ is perpendicular to it or vanishes. This is a paradox.

Comment: @my2cts I believe you're talking about the *orbital* angular momentum here, which is the $\bf{r}\times\bf{p}$, equivalent to the second term in my equation (1). A circularly polarized wave indeed bears no orbital angular momentum, but does bear spin (intrinsic) angular momentum.

Comment: @SeleneRoutley Actually when the gauge invariant formalism is used, there is no spin angular momentum. All of the angular momentum is expressed by $\bf J = \bf r \times \bf P$.

Comment: Edited comment: Note however that a circularly polarised plane wave does not carry angular momentum along its propagation direction if the Poynting vector is used. As $$\bf P = \epsilon_0 \bf E \times \bf B$$ is parallel to the propagation direction, $$\bf J = \bf r\times \bf P$$  is perpendicular to it or vanishes. This is a paradox.

Comment: @my2cts what do you mean by gauge invariant formalism? For example, equation (1) speaks only of physical fields, so is it not such a formalism? Perhaps you mean the frequency independent expressions involving only the transverse component $\mathbf{A}_\perp$ of the vector potential? I really don't follow where the paradox is at all, since your argument seems to deny the possibility of any fundamental excitation / particle bearing spin. At the quantum level, spin is the same as polarization.

Comment: @SeleneRoutley In the gauge invariant formalism the total angular momentum is given by $\bf J = \bf r \times \bf P$. There is no separate spin term.

Comment: @SeleneRoutley More precisely $J^{\lambda\mu\nu} = F^{\lambda\mu} x^\nu - F^{\lambda\nu} x^\mu$. The formula that you quote appears to be obtained by using the Noether (canonical) energy-momentum and then setting $\partial \bf A /  \partial t = \bf E$. I believe it is correct, but it is not part of gauge theory.

Comment: @my2cts indeed that is exactly where it covers from. The more restricted monochromatic formula, i.e. equation (1) above with $E$ alone, can also be derived from a classical torque on absorbing medium calculation considering a plane wave

Comment: @SeleneRoutley Spin conservation is incompatible gauge invariance. Spin is the conserved Noether current associated with symmetry under rotation of the em potential alone. Orbital angular momentum conservation is associated with rotation of the coordinate system. In gauge theory the two are mixed. After symmetrisation of energy-momentum there is no more room for spin so the AM takes the form of OAM. You may find my paper at https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078 interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Electromagnetic field of light has two kinds of angular momentum: spin angular momentum (SAM) and orbital angular momentum (OAM). The former represents the dynamical rotation of the electric (or magnetic) field around the propagation direction and indicates the polarization of the beam. The latter represents the rotation of light around the beam axis. The verification of these internal angular momentum can be see in light matter interaction, where the total angular momentum of systems remain conserved.