# Can $E=mc^2$ be proved at all , anyway?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

I have read many articles [questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178960/how-to-derive-e-mc2) and even the original paper, yet the actual proof of the formula escapes me.

I'd really appreciate it if someone can outline the logical skeleton of the proof, but my question goes even beyond that: What I mean is that the quantity of energy in one electron is a scalar that has no justification or reason, neither mathematical, nor logic, like the number of beans in a jar, how can its value be derived mathematically (from what formula[e]) or inferred logically (from what premises?)

Edit after the closure:

I did read the quoted links, what I am questioning here is the epistemology of those articles and links, what scientific value does such a proof have, if any?

Comment: It is proven in every second a billion times in the CERN. The mathematical side is a key element of the SR.

Comment: @peterh, could you please vote to reopen the question and explain how a value that can be only verified by experiment can be proven in any way?Do you consider Einstein's proof mathematical, logical or what?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43813/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178960/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic, all the links you are producing are *not* duplicates. I am questioning the epistemological valididy of what is called a *proof*. Why don't you allow people to express their views in answers? Even in the links you quote some worthy members like *annav* and *dmckee* state that the equivalence can*not* be proven, let alone derived!

Comment: @bob Well it can't be proven as in math. It can be proven that there is a lot of experimental evidence behind it, and there is nothing against it. Then we can use the induction hypothesis. I voted to reopen, but it probably won't be enough.