# von Laue's proof of $E=mc^2$

Tags: special-relativity, resource-recommendations, mass-energy, specific-reference

It is not widely known that the first correct proof of [$E=mc^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) was given by von Laue. Einstein never succeeded in giving complete and accurate proof. I came to know this when I was reading Hans Ohanion's book titled as "Einstein's Mistakes: The Human Failings of Genius".

Can anybody supply the PDF copy or web-link to this proof (in English)?

Comment: Other proofs: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43813/2451 ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178960/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It's a resource recommendation request more appropriate for History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange [1] rather than Physics Stack Exchange.  [1] https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dvij Requests for specific, hard to find references are on-topic on our site as per [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4490/50583).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am sure Wikipedia has the answer but it is quicker to pull it from my bookmarks: I velieve this is what you want.

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:On_the_Dynamics_of_the_Theory_of_Relativity

In passing, the tone of your question is poor: research is a collective endeavour and nobody, certainly not Einstein himself, has ever thought that he got all of special relativity and its consequences alone.